# Reading every paragraph in text file alone

Tags: c#

I want to read a text file which contains more than one paragraph separated by new lines. How to read every paragraph alone in `RichTextBox` and how to transfer to the next paragraph by button next and back to the first paragraph by button previous designed in the form. My code

```
private void LoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    dialog.Title = "Select a text file";
    dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (dialog.FileName != "")
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dialog.FileName);
        string Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        this.Input.TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.Input_TextChanged);
        Input.Clear();
        Input.Text = Text;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's with the unhooking of the `this.Input.TextChanged` event in a button click event?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(inputFilePath);
var paragraphs = text .Split('\n');
```

paragraphs will be an array of strings containing all the paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` to split it at `'\n'`.
Afterwards iterate through the array on the Button *next*.

```
private string[] paragraphs;
private int index = 0;
private void LoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
   dialog.Filter =
      "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
   dialog.Title = "Select a text file";

   dialog.ShowDialog();

   if (dialog.FileName != "")
   {
       System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dialog.FileName);
       string Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
       reader.Close();
       this.Input.TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.Input_TextChanged);
       Input.Clear();
       paragraphs = Text.Split('\n');
       index = 0;
       Input.Text = paragraphs[index];
   } 
} 

private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   index++;
   Input.Text = paragraphs[index];
}
```

(I know this might not be the most elegant solution but it should give an idea on what to do.)

Comment: ok Dominik it work well but how to handle the previous button action

Comment: just like the next but with `index--` instead of `index++`, and take care of the array bounds `index < 0` and `index >= arraylength`